# Sharing RAM/G5 Desktop/iMac

Tags: memory-management

I have a Mac G5 Desktop with 14GB of RAM installed which I sometimes use as a start up disk. I have a 27" iMac 2.8GHz Core i5 with only 4GB of RAM installed. Is there anyway I can access/utilise the RAM on the desktop via the iMac?

Answer (score 9):

[image]

There would be little practical purpose- ram's meant to be fast, and no matter how fast your network is, you'd get speeds slower than even a local drive (which could hold swap, which the system uses when it needs to free up ram). Firewire goes up to 800 Mbits per second. Even the crappier flavour of sata go up to 3Gbits/s (granted that's drive dependant). I think the closest you could get is to set up a ram drive on the g5, and use that for swap... exposed over NFS or AFS, and that, even if possible would end up being slow, *and* a horrible hack.

No, no, I'm afraid grumpy cat is right this time.